# VBA How to copy a Variant array to another one

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem with this sub:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim cell As Range
Dim arrayTmp(3) As Variant
Dim Occ As Long
arrayTmp = CountUnique(Selection)
'Controllo se l'utente seleziona un range che include più di 2 operatori'
If (arrayTmp(2) <> 2) Then
    MsgBox "Hai selezionato più di due operatori!" + Selection.Cells.Count
Else
    For Each cell In Selection
        If cell.Value = arrayTmp(0) Then
            cell.Value = arrayTmp(1)
        ElseIf cell.Value = arrayTmp(1) Then
            cell.Value = arrayTmp(0)
        End If
    Next cell
End If
End Sub
```

CountUnique(Selection) is a function that return a Variant array and it is:

```
Option Explicit
' This function returns an array which can hold multiple values.
Public Function CountUnique(dataRange As Range) As Variant
Dim dict As Dictionary
Dim cell As Range
Set dict = New Dictionary
Dim arr(3) As Variant

For Each cell In dataRange.Cells
    If Not dict.Exists(cell.Value) Then
                dict.Add cell.Value, 0
            End If
    If (dict.Count < 3) Then
        arr(dict.Count - 1) = cell.Value
    Else
        CountUnique = arr
    End If

Next
CountUnique = arr
End Function
```

I got a error for the instruction "arrayTmp = CountUnique(Selection)". The compiler tell me that it is impossible to assign the matrix. How can I fix it?

Comment: You are declaring `arrayTmp` as an array of four elements. Try `Dim arrayTmp As Variant`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thank you!